# What method can compare three integers? compareTo?

Tags: integer, compareto

Can compareTo compare 3 integers?  Reason I am asking is because I need to have a method that compares the month, day, and year to see if they are equal.

Comment: is there some particular language or framework or library or something you are working with?

Comment: Special sp = new Special(); 
 //dd, mo, and yy are Strings entered by the user
 //and read using the Scanner class
 if (sp.test(dd,mo,yy))
     System.out.println(dd +"\\"+ mo + "\\" + yy + " is special");
 else
     System.out.println(dd +"\\"+ mo + "\\" + yy +  " is NOT special");

Comment: I was given the above ^ code.  From what I understand, this is the main method.  What I need is to send that information (dd, mo, yy) to a method so that it will test to see if all of them are equal.  For example, if the date is 11/11/11, then it's equal.  If not, it will print it is not special.

Answer (score 0):

No, the traditional definition of `compareTo` only takes one argument - the object you're comparing against.

You should use an object that encapsulates the month, day, and year - that should be what you pass to your `compareTo` method instead of the raw values.